# How to UICollectionView with differing rows per column

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to make this layout, but Im not sure exactly how to have columns that have different amount of rows as the other columns, as well as making it Horizontal scroll.

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0):

While it might be possible to modify flow layout to do this, I think the best way would be to make a custom layout.

There are plenty of guides and tutorials out there for making custom layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with flow layout, the best way you can accomplish this would be by making each column a section and then returning different number of rows depending on the section.

> ```
> func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
>     return 4
> } 
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
>     switch section {
>     case 0:
>         return 2
>     case 1:
>         return 4
>     default:
>         return 2
>     }
> }
> ```